# Crop and stretch image to fill page using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, crop, stretch

I would like to crop and then non-proportionally stretch an image to fill the entire page. I suppose this is doable with just CSS and a proper DOM structure. I don't insist on the CSS solution. Even client-side JavaScript works for me, as long as I can download the full-size image from the server.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Jan

Comment: Object-fit might help you, ie11 needs polyfill though

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8fd4hrvm/ < this uses ` background-size: 200% 500%;
  background-position: calc(200% * .1) calc(500% * -.2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
.clip-me {
  clip-path: inset(10px 20px 0px 0px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 10%, 10% 10%, 10% 10%);
}
```

```html
<img class="clip-me" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png">
```

[This tool](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is pretty useful also.